# .NET Core 2.1 C# : send mail problem with same .dll. Correct in standalone console project .. and fail in main project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a big project in .NET Core 2.1 (I know, it's not updated to the last version, but for me it's ok) written in C#.

The problem I stumble is that time ago I wrote a little dll targetting .NET Standard 2.0 to send mails (using smtp).

The problem is that when I execute the code (`.SendMail()` in a console project), all its functioning and the mail are sent to the recipient correctly.

But when I created a nupkg package, import the library in the big project and try to use it with the same credential and recipient the mail has not been sent.

In debug console I receive the trace logs like :

```
Extenstion :250-smtpdh18.ad.aruba.it hello [151.xx.yyy.zzz], pleased to meet you250-HELP
Extenstion :250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
Extenstion :250-SIZE 524288000
Extenstion :250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Extenstion :250-8BITMIME
Extenstion :250 OK
Extenstion :
Reply to b64 2: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 Code :334
Reply to b64 3: 235 2.7.0 ... authentication succeeded Code :235
From Response :250 2.1.0 <tickets@domain.net> sender ok
Sent Response :250 2.0.0 qr0aqVrvbtWcAqr0aqSxAD mail accepted for delivery
221 2.0.0 smtpdh18.ad.aruba.it Aruba Outgoing Smtp  closing connection
```

To me it seems that all is ok. The host server says "mail accepted for delivery".

I do not understand why in a console stand alone project it's ok and in main project it fail.

Is there something special that I have to be aware of? Something to enable? Or what else?

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks

After several attempts I didn't find the cause of the problems so I need someone's help that experience something similar ...

Comment: maybe you need some custom SMTP configuration for `Core 2.1`  to override the defaults ?

Comment: This looks like the smtp server has taken the mail and is happy and when then something bad happened it did so on or after the smtp server. Do you control that smtp server?

Comment: Have you checked if the senders mailbox(when there is one) contain NDRs (non-delivery report) for this mails by now?

Comment: UPDATE : Hi Guys , Thanks for your suggestion. After struggeling my head I also want to to help someone else. I think i found a solution that seem to be related to DNS records  SPF txt.
So After talking with my provider we found that :
1. you have to enable "mail from adresses" validation ( to avoid spoofing )
2. you have to enable a SPF record in witch you enable "mail from adresses" domain